# Proof that $ax =1$ with no division and subtraction

Tags: proof-explanation, finite-fields

I need to proof that $ax = 1$  has one solution with no division and subtraction. It means that I can use only commutative,associative and distributive laws of multiplication and addition. Any suggestions on how to start?

Comment: What's the context? Are $a$ and $x$ elements of a group or something like that?

Comment: it is related with fields

Comment: Can you use the existence of multiplicative inverse or is that what you mean by "division"?

Comment: In what context? And what are your thoughts?

Comment: @Javi I can use multiplicative inverse.

Comment: start with $x=1.x=(a^{-1}a)x=\cdots$

Comment: I was thinking of assuming that ax1 = 1 and ax2 = 1 and then to show that x1 = x2. However, I cannot eliminate a.

Comment: ok! $x_1=1 \cdot x_1=(a^{-1}a)x_1=a^{-1}(ax_1)=a^{-1}(ax_2)=\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically asking about unicity of (right) multiplicative inverse.

Assume $a$ has two inverses $b$ and $c$, i.e., $ab=ac=1$. Then, using associativity and commutativity of the product

$b=1\cdot b=(c\cdot a)\cdot b=(a\cdot c)\cdot b=c\cdot(a\cdot b)=c\cdot 1=c$.